# SSH SFTP and Mounting File Shares

Tags: finder, osx-server, ssh, mount, sftp

Quick question:

I know how to mount an SFTP connection in Finder using Transmit, but, at least in my setup, it only mounts the subdirectories in the User's folder (i.e., Desktop, Documents, etc.). How do I mount other partitions? For example, I have a partition that contains the files for my web server, and I would like to be able to edit them remotely.

Comment: What is the Remote Path set to in your Transmit favorite?  Try setting it to / if it's not set at all.

Comment: Well, if I set it to nothing, it of course goes to the /Users folder. If I set it to root, I get everything in the OS partition, but not on the other partitions.